# Code only checks the brightness of the first pixel of the bitmap/image in C#

Tags: c#, text, bitmap, ascii

I'm currently working on an image-to-ASCII converter in C# and ran into a problem. I want the program to run through every single pixel, get the brightness and add the right character in. But in my code it only checks the first pixel of the image, so pixel 0-0, and prints it in the .txt file successfully without showing any error messages. I've tried using StreamWriter, but the same result came out, which means that it might have something to do with my for loop. What have I done wrong?

```
        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(source);

        int width = bm.Width; // Image width
        int height = bm.Height; // Image height

        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) 
        {
            int w = 0;
            w++;
            int h = 0;

            file = source + " ASCII.txt";

            if(i > width)
            {
                h++;
            }

            System.Drawing.Color pixelColor = bm.GetPixel(i, h);
            float brightness = pixelColor.GetBrightness();

            using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(file))
            {
                writer.Close();  // Creating file
            }
                
            // ASCII print

            if (brightness < 0.14)
            {
                File.AppendAllText(file, "@");

                if (w > width)
                { 
                    File.AppendAllText(file, "\n");
                }
            }

            if (brightness > 0.14 && brightness < 0.28)
            {
               
                 File.AppendAllText(file, "%");

                 if (w > width)
                 {
                     File.AppendAllText(file, "\n");
                 }
                
            }

            if (brightness > 0.28 && brightness < 0.42)
            {
                
                File.AppendAllText(file, "#");

                if (w > width)
                {
                    File.AppendAllText(file, "\n");
                }
                
            }

            if (brightness > 0.42 && brightness < 0.56)
            {
                
                File.AppendAllText(file, "*");

                if (w > width)
                {
                    File.AppendAllText(file, "\n");
                }
                
            }

            if (brightness > 0.56 && brightness < 0.7)
            {
               
                File.AppendAllText(file, "+");

                if (w > width)
                {
                    File.AppendAllText(file, "\n");
                }
                
            }

            if (brightness > 0.7 && brightness < 0.84)
            {
                
                File.AppendAllText(file, "=");

                if (w > width)
                {
                    File.AppendAllText(file, "\n");
                }
                
            }

            if (brightness > 0.84 && brightness < 0.98)
            {
               
                File.AppendAllText(file, "-");

                if (w > width)
                {
                    File.AppendAllText(file, "\n");
                }
                
            }

            if (brightness > 0.98)
            {
                File.AppendAllText(file, ":");

                if (w > width)
                {
                        File.AppendAllText(file, "\n");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020406/travel-through-pixels-in-bmp

Answer (score 3):

Not expert in C#.

But in your for loop condition, i < width, then the block will only execute when i < width; but then you increment h when i > width, will this ever get hit?